# why the moment get start of month is 12:00 of first day

Tags: javascript

I want to use moment to get start of month and end of month, this is my code:

```
const startOfMonth = moment().subtract(monthCount,'month').clone().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss SSS');

const endOfMonth = moment().subtract(monthCount,'month').clone().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss SSS');
```

but the start of month is: `2021-05-01 12:00:00 000` the end of month is: `2021-05-31 11:59:59 999`. why the month start from 12:00 of first day?

could it be start of month:`2021-05-01 00:00:00 000` end of month:`2021-05-31 23:59:59 999`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual time value is correct; you are just formatting it in 12-hour time. There's no hour 0 in 12-hour time; midnight is 12:00 AM. Try HH for your hour format.